# Config browserify for react templates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, parse-error, react-templates

I have a problem when building the bundle.js file with Browserify and Babel.

Header.js:

```
import HeaderRT from './Header.rt';
```

Header.rt:

```
<div>Header></div>
```

Error:

```
Browserify Error
.../Header.rt:1
<div>Header</div>
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

As i understand, all of ".rt" files need to be processed by react-templates but not by Browserify. But how can i config that ?

This is my gulp file:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var fs          = require("fs");
var browserify  = require("browserify");
var babelify    = require("babelify");
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gutil       = require('gulp-util');
var inject      = require('gulp-inject');
var rename      = require('gulp-rename');
var clean       = require('gulp-clean');
var debug       = require('gulp-debug');
var watchify    = require('watchify');
var assign      = require('lodash.assign');
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var rt          = require('gulp-react-templates');

var customOpts = {
    entries: ['./main.js'],
    debug: true,
    ignoreTransform: ['rt']
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts));
b.transform(babelify);

gulp.task('js', bundle);
b.on('update', bundle);
b.on('log', gutil.log);

gulp.task('default', ['js']);

function bundle() {
    gulp.src('./dist/*.js', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());

    var bundleFile = b.bundle()
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('./bundle.js'))
        .pipe(rename('bundle_' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100000) + '.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

    gulp.src('./index.html')
        .pipe(inject(bundleFile))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

    return bundleFile;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out how to do that by using **react-templatify**. For someone who has the same problem, we just need to add this line to browserify's config:

```
transform: ['react-templatify']
```

So its config becomes:

```
var customOpts = {
    entries: ['./main.js'],
    debug: true,
    transform: ['react-templatify']
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
```